# C#: Storing Filesize in Database

Tags: c#, database, file-io

I'm storing objects in a database as varbinary(MAX) and want to know their filesize.  Without getting into the pro and cons of using the varbinary(MAX) datatype, what is the best way to read the file size of an object stored in the database?

Is it:

A. Better to just read the column from the DB and call the .Length property of System.Data.Linq.Binary.

OR

B. Better to determine the file size of the object before it is added to the DB and create another column called Size.

The files I'm dealing with are generally between 0 and 3 MB with a skew towards the smaller size.  It doesn't necessarily make sense to hit the DB again for the file size, but it also doesn't really make sense to read through the entire item to determine its length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add a calculated column in your database that would be DATALENGTH([your_col])?

Comment: Because that's _too_ good of an idea.  Will mark as answer when the timer expires.